# I am trying to take the contents of fa plain txt file and put it into a char array, then I would like to print it out of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
  

    #include <stdio.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arraySize = 100;
    char file[arraySize];
    fstream myfile;
    
    //open file
    myfile.open("SamplePlainText.txt", ios::binary);
    

    myfile.read(file, sizeof(file));
    myfile.write(file, sizeof(file));

    for(int i=0; i< arraySize; i++) { 
        cout << file[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

I am trying to copy the contents of a plain txt file that says "This is a test." into a char array so I can read the information back out of the array using a for loop. Whenever I compile/run the program I am getting a bunch of random numbers and can't figure out where my error is. Any suggestions? (Its only my second semester programming so forgive me if this is not good. This is exactly what I ran on xcode )

Comment: This file was not opened for reading or writing making the results of reading and writing... questionable. Read up on the file open modes in the documentation for `open` for details.

Comment: ALWAYS inspect the stream state after any IO transaction to ensure that the transaction was performed successfully. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/o5o771sEv

Comment: @tenfour I updated it with what I ran on xcode exactly. apologies I am a student this is all very new for me

Comment: If `arraySize` bytes were not read from the file, printing `arraySize` bytes will result in printing some number of uninitialized values being printed. This is typically seen as garbage.

Comment: @user4581301 I see, allow me a moment to take a look at that. This is my second semester learning so apologies if I seem like a level 1 noob. If I am reading correctly, the conditions if statement resulted in Arrrrrrgh being printed. Does that mean the problem is with accessing the actual contents of the file?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel got it, updated with exactly what I ran on xcode

Comment: Yes. The file failed to open, so I printed out a brief message to notify the user and exited the program before it could attempt to use the data which was not read.

Comment: Note in your case the file likely exists and will be opened, but since the file was not opened for reading, the read likely fails.

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

1. The file was not opened for reading or writing and cannot be read or written.
2. The read was not tested for success before actions were taken on the data read.
3. The entire buffer was printed regardless of how much, or little, data was read. Writing more data than was read results in printing whatever already existed in the buffer. This often looks like garbage.

Modified and annotated code:

```cpp
//#include <stdio.h> not required
#include <fstream>
//#include <string> not required
#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib> not required
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int arraySize = 100; // must use constant values to size arrays
    char file[arraySize];
    ifstream myfile; // file opened for input.
    // currently cannot write to file. reading from and writing to the same file 
    // stream is exceptionally hard to get right. For now don't even try. 
    // If you must read and write the same file: 
    //    Read the file into buffer
    //    Modify data in buffer
    //    Close the stream. 
    //    Open the file for writing. 
    //    Write the buffer to the file. 
    //    Close the stream.
    // In this case writing exactly what was read back to the file is pointless, 
    // so I left it out.
    
    //open file
    myfile.open("SamplePlainText.txt",
                ios::binary); // ifstream implies opened for reading
    

    if (myfile.read(file, sizeof(file)))
    { // printing the data read is only meaningful if data was read
        for(int i=0; 
            i< myfile.gcount(); // only print up to number of bytes read 
            i++) {  
            cout << file[i] << endl; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File was not read" << endl;
    }
//    myfile.write(file, sizeof(file));
// left out for now
}
```